# How to hide azure clientID and authentication js code from user while using google OAuth?

Tags: javascript, azure, frontend, backend, azure-mobile-services

How to hide azure clientID and authentication js code from user while using google OAuth? The code is always visible to inspection as the javascript code is linked to the html. Im not very good with javascript.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This is not clear enough to answer.  Could you give more details about your app, how it works and how it is associated with Azure Mobile Services?   A code sample from your app would be appreciated as well.  You can de-identify the clientID.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide it and it's not meant to be a security feature. A consequence of using HTML/JavaScript is that the code is visible.

If you use server directed auth with Google, you won't risk leaking any secrets to the world since you'll have locked down the callback URL for getting the token to your service.